# Jupyter notebook python nameerror

Tags: python, json, pandas, scikit-learn

I have the following `NameError` and I'm not sure why. I've only changed the input file path and the column names from a tutorial which worked for me.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

file = 'cuisine_ingredients.json'
with open(file) as train_file:
   json = json.load(train_file)

train = pd.concat(map(pd.DataFrame,json))
train.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)

unique_cuisines = train['cuisine'].nunique()

labelEncoder_cuisine = LabelEncoder()
labelEncoder_cuisine.fit(train['cuisine'])
train['cuisine'] = labelEncoder_cuisine.transform(train['cuisine'])

labelEncoder_ingredients = LabelEncoder()
labelEncoder_ingredients.fit(train['ingredients'])
train['ingredients'] = 
labelEncoder_ingredients.transform(train['ingredients'])

X = np.array(train.drop(['id'], 1).astype(float))

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)

kmeans.fit(X_scaled)

KMeans(algorithm='auto', copy_x=True, init='k-means++', max_iter=600,
n_clusters=unique_cuisines, n_init=10, n_jobs=1, precompute_distances='auto',
random_state=None, tol=0.0001, verbose=0)
```

I keep getting `NameError: name 'kmeans' is not defined` for `kmeans.fit(X_scaled)`.

Cheers :)

Comment: Then I get this error: "fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'"

Comment: You have not defined the variable `kmeans` anywhere, so the python interpreter tells you it cannot find it. It's probably in one of the previous cells in the notebook

Answer (score 0):

I've only briefly looked at your code, but it looks like you haven't defined `kmeans` (lowercase k and m) as you've written it in `kmeans.fit()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `KMeans().fit(X_scaled)` instead of `kmeans.fit(X_scaled)`. In scikit-learn you have to instantiate a model first before you can fit to it.

I don't know what the author of the notebook intended but usually you want to save your model to a variable, so you could also write it the following way:

```
kmeans = KMeans()
kmeans.fit(X_scaled)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swap these 2 lines of code.

```
kmeans.fit(X_scaled)

KMeans(algorithm='auto', copy_x=True, init='k-means++', max_iter=600,
n_clusters=unique_cuisines, n_init=10, n_jobs=1, precompute_distances='auto',
random_state=None, tol=0.0001, verbose=0)
```

After which, you will probably want the results:

```
X_transformed = kmeans.transform(X_scaled)
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your model based on your parameters first.

```
kmeans = KMeans(algorithm='auto', copy_x=True, init='k-means++', max_iter=600,n_clusters=unique_cuisines, n_init=10, n_jobs=1, precompute_distances='auto',random_state=None, tol=0.0001, verbose=0)
```

Once the model is initialized then you can try to fit the data.

```
kmeans.fit(X_scaled)
```